# Use ScrollToTop in react (but not for every link - how to do it)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

I need to use ScrollToTop, but not for every link. What is the best way to do this? Adding a function to every link where I want to use this function seems like the wrong way. I was also thinking about wrapping all components  `<ScrollToTop>(all components and routes)</ScrollToTop>` and excluding only the places where I don't want to use it - just not sure how to do that. I've tried to find the answer, but I guess no one has asked this, or I can't find it.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can create a Higher order component which has this ScrollToTop functionality. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

let scrollToTop = () =>{window.scrollTo(0,0)}